# How do you test whether or not a ConTeXt module is installed?

Tags: context

How do you test whether or not a ConTeXt module is installed? I have run `first-setup.bat --modules=all` but how do I test if all the modules are installed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Method 1 (assuming ConTeXt standalone in installed in `/opt/context`

List all the directories in `texmf-modules` tree:

```
ls /opt/context/tex/texmf-modules/tex/context/third
```

(or `ls /opt/context-minimals/texmf-modules/tex/context/third` if you run context-minimals installed from AUR repository using Arch and derivatives)

### Method 2: To check for a specific module

ConTeXt third party modules are named `t-<modulename>.{tex,mkii,mkiv}`. So you can run

```
mtxrun t-<modulename>.tex t-<modulename>.mkii t-<modulename>.mkiv
```

If the module is present, the above command will return the location of the module.

Comment: Mine is installed in `c:\context\ ` but when I look in the folder `texmf-modules` it only has an `ls-R` file.

Comment: Then the modules are not installed. I don't use Windows, so I don't know what goes wrong in the installation process.

Comment: How would you know the version of the module? That is, if it is the most updated version.

Comment: @azetina: Depends on the module writer. In all the modules that I have written, I include a statement that gives the release date of the module. The only way to check if you have the most up to date version is to compare the release date from the versions on contextgarden or ctan.